# how renderer pivottable.js output in grid format

Tags: jquery, angularjs

hi actually i do project on pivot.js. In pivot.js output is renderer in table format .but my question is output is  in ui-grid format.please send answer to how to do for excat result.

Comment: Please send code so we can see what is the problem.